# In Odoo V9 values entered in One2many field form disapper when clicked on "Save" button

Tags: odoo-9

I have form of One2many field and when entered values in it and click on Save then windows going to loading/Refresh and then values disappeared. I enter values for all (say 10) record in same time move to next field by using tab or enter key values show at that time but not saved after "Save" button click.
But if I entered for 3 or 5 or 8 then this was save and showed successfully. What is the issue here? I am using Odoo v9. I also override the "write" method.

Comment: Check if you have a domain in that one2many and also check if the records you created are within that domain

Comment: I found the problem. When entering values fast, response of request for "search-read" send by browser are not return back by the server and by click "Save" button request for "write" also is in pending so that’s why my changes are not save. What is solution about that server response problem?

Comment: Go slowly hahah. Maybe you should write an issue in the Odoo Project in Git Hub. Good luck